# Insert data in a loop in jaydata

Tags: javascript, loops, insertion, jaydata

I have an array of objects and want to insert them in a table but only first one record is inserted and rest are not

```
data.forEach(function(obj){         
    mydb.tasks.add(obj);
    mydb.saveChanges(); 
});
```

here is what I am actually doing

```
data.forEach(function(obj){

    mydb[table].filter("it._id == '"+obj._id+"'")
    .toArray( function(objs){

        if(!objs.length){
            mydb[table].add(obj);
            mydb.saveChanges();  
        }

    });         

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move savechanges out of the loop or use our other api called itemstore api

Comment: i tried it by taking savechanges out of loop but still only first obj is stored, is there a way to add more than one records simultaneously ? 
like  mydb[table].add(all_objs);